# Multiple versions of Ipython installed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pip, ipython

I have installed several ipython versions on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. If I run

```
$ ipython --version
```

i get :

```
ipython (1.2.1)
```

and running

```
$  pip list
```

shows:

```
ipython (3.1.0)
```

How can I uninstall the first version and call the ipython I have installed from pip?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "It depends..." Could you please tell us how did you install `ipython` on your system or, at least, which kind of system (OS X? Debian? Red Hat? Gentoo? ...) are you dealing with? Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm not sure, how the first ipython was installed, but the second one (The version 3.1.0), has been installed using pip. Thank you.

Comment: Then `sudo apt-get remove ipython*` should do the trick